# Creating a 'Like' system with HTML/CSS/Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been working on a [project](http://yosemite-widget.site90.net) (you should probably see the link to better understand what I am talking about). To make things better, I decided to make a *like* system.

Each posts contain a *like* button and a number next to it that indicates how many people *liked* the post.

```
Like (4)
```

The current one in my project is just plain text with an empty link, and the number is a dummy.

```
<a href = "">Like</a> (4)
```

Is it possible to actually make the *like* button actually work? What would I need to use?

Comment: due to the amount of like tabs your going to have a database to store the id of said like tab and the amount of times its been "liked" to then echo out would prob be your best bet

Comment: Do you know how I would do that exactly? That's kinda where I'm stuck... How do I exactly _have a database_?

Comment: most web hosting companies include databases s part of the hosting package, but once you find where yours is there are many tutorials on how to connect to it through your site and put data in and pull data out

Comment: i would use facebook's so that people can't cheat and you don't have to learn a ton of crap for one task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need php/SQL to keep track of the votes made. So you need to learn php and SQL or rely on an extension someone else made. If you happen to use one of the more popular CMS's (Joomla/Wordpress) you can probably get it without ever having to worry about the coding.